# Angular remove Element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive:

```
app.directive('eventView', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace:true,
    templateUrl: 'partials/EventView.html',
    controller: 'eventController',
    link: function(scope, element){  
        scope.$on("$destroy",function() {
            element.remove();
        }); 
    }
  }
});
```

The controller for the directive:

```
app.controller('eventController', function($scope, $rootScope){
  $scope.removeEvent = function (){
    $scope.$broadcast("$destroy")
  }
});
```

There are several instances of the same directives in the rootscope. Each directive is a div in which there is a remove button which is bind to the removeEvent method in the controller definition.

The problem is that when a remove button is pressed in one those div(from eventView directive), all the divs are being removed. I only want the current directive from where the destroy is being broadcasted to be removed. I know its because i'm broadcasting `$scope.$broadcast("$destroy")` but how can I remove only the current scope, is there a predefined method only for that current scope

Comment: Are these divs rendered thru ng_repeat or do they have some unique identifier??

Comment: You should investigate on isolated scopes. Your directives needs to know which scope it's referring to. Here's a good article: http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/

Comment: @HarishR, its not part of ng_repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using ng-repeat then you can use $index as the unique identifier for those div...
just update your code like below:

```
app.directive('eventView', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace:true,
    templateUrl: 'partials/EventView.html',
    controller: 'eventController',
    link: function(scope, element){  
        scope.$on("$destroy" + identifier,function() {
            element.remove();
        }); 
    },
    scope: {identifier : '@'}
  }
});
```

and broadcast the event with identifier

```
app.controller('eventController', function($scope, $rootScope){
  $scope.removeEvent = function (identifier){
    $scope.$broadcast("$destroy" + identifier)
  }
});
```

if the divs are not part of ng-repeat, then you will need to have some kind of identifier to identify which div to destroy...

Comment: so, I understand, I should replace scope: {identifier : '@'} where @ with an identifier

Comment: whereever you are using this directive you need to pass identifier with it: `<event-view identifier="{{$index}}"></event-view>`

Comment: in the link function, function(scope, element){  
        scope.$on("$destroy" + identifier,function() {
            element.remove();
        }); I'm getting an error that identifier doesn't exist

Comment: identifier is a value which I'll be keeping in a scope variable, the issue is that whenever i update the scope identifier, it is updating in all directives scopes

Comment: use isolate scope, like the one in my example.. to keep separate instance for each directive... also you are getting that error because i guess you have not added the isolate scope..

Comment: as per your example, this line scope.$on("$destroy" + identifier,function() { is giving error that identifier is not defined,

Comment: do u have isolate scope defined??

Comment: Yes, I created a new question here with the new codes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24722559/removing-directive-using-isolated-scopes