# Removing Directive using Isolated Scopes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm having several directives in a container where I need to be able to remove each of them specifically. Each directive is in a big a div which contains a remove button as well.

The controller:

```
app.controller('eventController', function($scope, $rootScope){;    
  $scope.removeEvent = function (id){
    console.log(id);
    $scope.$broadcast("$destroy" + id);
  }
});
```

The directive:

```
app.directive('eventView', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace:true,
    templateUrl: 'partials/EventView.html',
    controller: 'eventController',
    scope: {id : '@'},
    link: function(scope, element){  
        scope.$on("$destroy"+scope.id,function() {
            element.remove();
        }); 
    }
  }
});
```

The issue is that I'm getting an error with this line `scope.$on("$destroy"+scope.id,function() {` saying that id is undefined

to add the directive:

```
app.controller('AddTimelineController', function($scope, $rootScope,$compile){
  $scope.id = 0;
  $scope.addEvent = function (){
    newElement = $compile("<event-View id=\"{{id}}\"></event-View>")($scope);
    $scope.id = $scope.id+1;
    eventContainer = angular.element(document.getElementById('eventContainer'));
    eventContainer.append(newElement);
  }
});
```

To remove the directive:

```
app.controller('eventController', function($scope, $rootScope){;    
  $scope.removeEvent = function (id){
    console.log(id);
    $scope.$broadcast("$destroy" + id);
  }
});
```

Comment: can u please provide the html as well?? how are you invoking the directive??

Comment: okk, i put the whole codes

Comment: @HarishR, Done, just updated the question with all the codes

Comment: Put your html code from where you call your directive.

Comment: please setup the plunker.. plus why are you not using ng-repeat on event count?? that would be much simpler...

Comment: no, i can't use ng-repeat, because the events gets added only when I click on a button

Comment: didn't get, how is button click stoping you from using ng-repeat, ng-repeat does dynamically display the added elements.. and thats what exactly you want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead using `$broadcast` I would use `$watch` into `link` that will listen on `id` change.

See Demo in <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3itheh4dXBkfA35krPTS?p=preview)</kbd>

It's true that `$watch()` is doing dirt-checking vs  `$broadcast()`and `$broadcast()` is cheaper than `$watch()`.

However in your case you call the `link` before `removeEvent` is called and therefore directive doesn't see proper `id` you use.